How to Place an Export Button Next to Table Filters in Laravel Filament
I'm using Laravel Filament and want to modify the position of the Export button in my tables. Instead of having it on a separate header row or the 'bulk actions' functionality, I would like to place the button next to the table filters. The goal is to maintain the functionality where clicking the Export button exports all filtered items, not just selected ones like 'bulk actions' does. Here's the relevant part of my SiteResource class:
PHP:
use pxlrbt\FilamentExcel\Actions\Tables\ExportAction;
use Filament\Tables;

class SiteResource extends Resource
{
public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
    return $table
        ->columns([
            // columns definitions
        ])
        ->filters([
            // filters definitions
        ])
        ->HeaderActions([
            ExportAction::make()
        ]);
    }
}

Goal: Move the Export button so that it appears next to the search and filter options at the top of the table, as shown in my layout:

How can I achieve this modification of removing the header row while keeping the functionality of exporting all filtered items unlike using the bulk actions option (which I find to be very clunky)?

did you acheive that ?

No, still uncertain on how to get this done. I was looking at non filament solutions.

This can be achieved using Render Hooks. For this you would use:
TablesRenderHook::TOOLBAR_SEARCH_AFTER

After the search container
Here's a guide on how to implement this. See #6

This is super useful. Looking into this.
